# Why does this class, when the method onResume is called, give error NullPointerException?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, onresume

```
public class Scores extends Activity {

TextView tvPoints;
TextView tvRecord;

int record = 0;
int points = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    tvPoints = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPoints);
    tvRecord = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRecord);

    points = getIntent().getIntExtra("points", 0);
    record = getIntent().getIntExtra("record", 0);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    tvPoints.setText("Points: "+points);
    tvRecord.setText("Record: "+record);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The layout should be loaded first. You forget to call `setContentView()`.

That's why these controls

```
tvPoints = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPoints);
tvRecord = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRecord);
```

return `null`

Comment: ahahhah thank you! i was struggling for such a dumb oversight! thank you very much =)